# Scroll View Zooming Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am using a scroll view to use the zoom feature and I have multiple images in a view and whenever I run it, this error occurs.

[image: Code]

I am wondering how to fix this error, and if I am using the view correctly. Also, if anyone knows what the error means, please tell me.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 3.0
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you connect `scrollView` to the scroll view in `Interface Builder`?

Comment: @OzgurVatansever are you meaning the code scrollView is connected to the actual scroll view? in that case, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the code and it works perfectly on mine using Swift 3.0. I would suggest to start a new project and copy your code.

Comment: The thing is, I've done that. I'm guessing the project is just corrupted. Although, I don't know what I've been doing wrong in terms of just dragging and dropping pictures and image views and stuff in the View Controllers. I've only linked each Controller to each other with a button.